# List hidden commits still in Github but not Git (security leak)

Tags: github, github-api

AWS informed me of leaked account info in a Github repo. It gave me link to the corresponding commit. That commit seems to only be visible if you have the direct sha. I am trying to identify all the other commits that could also contain leaks.

AWS gave the link: `https://github.com/myorg/somerepo/commit/1abcdef` and that gives me a very old commit with a banner

```
This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.
```

If I try `git show 1abcdef` on that repo, it's not found. It really cannot be found in git itself. In fact, there is nothing that old.

If I access the commit through the Github API, it is there:

```
gh api 'repos/myorg/somerepo/commits/1abcdef
```

I can see all information about it, including the date in 2017.

So I tried:

```
gh api 'repos/myorg/somerepo/commits?until=2017-12-31'
```

But that finds nothing. The Github API doesn't seem to mention anything to look at orphaned commits.

I have obviously rotated all credentials for the compromised (dev) account but how can I find other potential problematic commits? If I cannot find them, how could a hacker do it?

Comment: Have you managed to find anything else on this? If not, probably asking GitHub customer support is a good idea.